# Monitor ROS2 middleware

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

We are currently developing a ROS2 system whereby we classify images coming from a GigE camera. In our system we have a node that pulls the images from the camera, a node that classifies the images and finally a node that saves certain images. However we notice that not all nodes are receiving the images equally, some nodes receive less images than sent from the camera driver. We detected this via internal counters in the nodes (QoS is set to reliable). However we have no idea where the images are lost in the system. So therefore our question is whether there is a way to monitor a ROS2 system whereby we can where these are lost, see the dropped message count etc. We suspect that a queue might be filled up, but we seem to find no way to verify this.

Kind regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/392826/monitor-ros2-middleware/) by [Gintecc](https://answers.ros.org/users/91581/gintecc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-12-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS 2 is built on DDS you could try a DDS monitor to check the message passing at the DDS layer.
If you are using FastDDS this could work.
https://eprosima.com/index.php/products-all/eprosima-fast-dds-monitor

---

Originally posted by [Shawn Schaerer](https://answers.ros.org/users/23929/shawn-schaerer/) with karma: 106 on 2021-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gintecc](https://answers.ros.org/users/91581/gintecc/) on 2021-12-21**:
Thank you! Is was a bit of struggle to get working, but now it is fine.